# Pushing to array causes error in Vuejs when attempting to add data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working on an infinite scroll solution and I am trying to push data onto an array of objects, but I am getting an error:

```
vue.common.js?e881:2643 [Vue warn]: Error when rendering anonymous component at /Users/Deric/Sites/mobile/lawn-mobile/src/components/jobs/index.vue: warn @ vue.common.js?e881:2643Vue._render @ vue.common.js?e881:2253(anonymous function) @ vue.common.js?e881:1699get @ vue.common.js?e881:736run @ vue.common.js?e881:805flushSchedulerQueue @ vue.common.js?e881:623nextTickHandler @ vue.common.js?e881:401
vue.common.js?e881:2262 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined(…)
```

If i just set the data, it works, but the infinite scroll overwrites the data instead of appending to it. Here is my data object:

```
data () {
  return {
    jobs: [],
```

and here is my http call:

```
getJobs(pageNumber = 1) {
  let api = SessionStorage.get.item('api')
  let url = `${api.base_url}jobs?page=${pageNumber}`
  this.$http.get(url).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.body.data)
    this.jobs.push(response.body.data)
```

The `console.log` looks like this:

[image]

What is the trick to getting this to work? I have also tried `concat` but that doesn't work either.

Comment: My guess is to check if `this` refers to right object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using concat correctly, i.e.

```
this.jobs = this.jobs.concat(response.body.data)
```

only if the output of your console.log is correct this should give you an array of objects which seems to be what you are after.

Comment: I bet this is the reason. I was not assigning it to my jobs variable but instead using it more like then push method. I'll test as soon as I get home.

Comment: That was the trick! I was doing this: `this.jobs.concat(response.body.data)` think it would "push" the data instead of reassigning the variable. Thanks!

Comment: hello, can you explain to me why the concat works but not the push I don't understand

Comment: @Snoxik so long as `this` is referencing the reactive component then `this.jobs.push()` will work as expected - I don't use `this.$http` anymore but with axios and async/await the above example should work with either method.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `this` is not pointing to correct object, try following-

```
getJobs(pageNumber = 1) {
  let api = SessionStorage.get.item('api')
  let url = `${api.base_url}jobs?page=${pageNumber}`
  let self = this 
  this.$http.get(url).then((response) => {
    console.log(self.jobs)
    console.log(response.body.data)
    self.jobs.push(response.body.data)
```